# Shared files with symbolic links

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

Our company has really two apps.  We rebrand our apps for other companies.

In AngularJS  we started to create a folder, then symbolic link to the files in some shared directory. This allowed us to have different apps package names in config.xml files, but still use the same code.

We are in the process of convert over to Angular 4 and Ionic.  I'm trying to do the same things.

```
./
--MobileApps
(The real files)
--assets
--dataModels
--node_modules
--pages
--apps
```

so forth

Then in the apps folder each app
App 1
App 2

In App 1 folder it has symbolic links back to the other files

```
--node_moduels
--src/assets
--src/config
--src/dataModels
--app/pages
```

I moved all the files around.  I think Visual Code knew I did that and wants to link back to the real files (I think).

I go to folder App 1, and do Ionic Build. I get errors

> Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Mobile-Apps/dataModels/something.model.js'
>       at Error (native)
>    @ ./src/app/app.module.ts 24:0-70 25:0-74
>    @ ./src/app/main.ts,/Mobile-Apps/dataModels/something.model.ts

This is correct I don't have any JS file in that folder. Not sure how to get it to build there.  Or what is going on.

I wanted to clear cache, so I tried to delete node_models and reinstall using npm install.  Not sure if that actually did anything.

Any ideas?

Comment: That is the question, it seems like ionic or angular doesn't like symbolic link.

I have my src/dataModels  
ionic build  builds fine. 

change dataModels to be a symlink 
get the error.  The folder exists (just links to a different path). 

Nothing in app.module.ts changed.  The path should in theory be the same.
But Ionic throws error.   Delete symlink and move the file back. works fine.

Comment: tsconfig.json has include src/**  I guess when it gets compiles, it doesn't look past the src directory and thus couldn't find the link path correctly. 
Now my tsconfig.json  include looks like

"include": [
    "../../dataModels",
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ]
seems to work.

Comment: Bummer.  One of our newer programers is on windows.  We don't think these symbolic links I create in Linux will work.  Might have to just set up a different script that sets up the symbolic links on windows.